# How to throw error when no node is found using OpenXML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I would like to ask how to throw an error in SQL Server when the XML is parsed using OpenXML. Here is an example from Microsoft:

```
Insert Into Employee 
SELECT   EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
    FROM       OPENXML (@hdoc, '/NewDataSet/Employee',1)
WITH (EmployeeId Integer, FirstName varchar(100),  LastName varchar(100))  XMLEmployee
Where XMLEmployee.EmployeeId Not IN (Select EmployeeID from Employee)
```

What if the root node exists but there is no Employee in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '<NewDataSet></NewDataSet>'

IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    WHERE @XML.exist('/NewDataSet/Employee') = 1
) RAISERROR('Employee not exists', 16, 1)
```

Full answer (maybe wrong answer, because I need to see XML structure) -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '<NewDataSet></NewDataSet>'

IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    WHERE @XML.exist('/NewDataSet/Employee') = 1
) RAISERROR('Employee not exists', 16, 1)

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT
      t.c.value('@EmployeeId', 'INT')
    , t.c.value('@FirstName', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    , t.c.value('@LastName', 'VARCHAR(100)') 
FROM @XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/Employee') t(c)
WHERE t.c.value('@EmployeeId', 'INT') NOT IN (
    SELECT EmployeeID 
    FROM dbo.Employee
)
```